I have knobs for a dresser drawer, but the fasteners are not with them. What are fasteners? Came w/tiny screws



The baby screws in pic were screwed in but the depth is tiny... I looked up fasteners but they didn't look right. I will take a pic of drawers as well. Don't know what fasteners are really so I don't know how to use them or what kind of buy or anything. What kind of fasteners are these and how do I find more?

A picture would be of help. Edit the question to add it.

Without a pic we are guessing.  Even with a picture it would be impossible to tell what thread is needed if the attachment is a screw. Our only advice would be "get the correct size screws."   The best advice is for you to take the knobs to a hardware store, ( not a big box orange or blue store). Have the helpful people there find what you need.  Help them by knowing what the thickness of the drawer front is.

Take the knob to the hardware store, preferably, a small, locally-owned one (a big-box will do). Either ask the guy behind the counter or try the knob on the "thread identifier" board that's located near the screws. That'll tell you the thread & pitch. Then, you need a screw long enough to go through the drawer face and into the knob, but not so long that it'll bottom out in the knob before getting tight.

Without a photo I have to guess, but... Typically these attach with bolts extending through the drawer front from inside. If you take the knob to a hardware store you should be able to find the right size and thread of bolt; using that information and the thickness of the drawer front you should be able to make a reasonable guess at the appropriate bolt length. If in doubt, err on the short side.

In metric land, M4 would be a good first guess.

Modern non-metric 8-32 is the other first guess.
